# Модульное тестирование в erlang

Tags: erlang, юнит-тесты

Никто не сталкивался с такой ошибкой при использовании eUnit в erlang?

```
{eunit_proc,buffer_to_binary,1,
    [{file,"eunit_proc.erl"},{line,276}]},
{eunit_proc,group_leader_loop,3,
    [{file,"eunit_proc.erl"},{line,600}]}]}
```

eunit_proc.erl https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/eunit/src/eunit_proc.erl#L276

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 6-May-2015::15:09:39 ===
Error in process <0.1057.0> with exit value: {badarg,[{erlang,list_to_binary,[[[100,101,99,111,100,101,32,114,116,109,112,44,32,99,104,117,110,107,32,105,100,58,32,"4","\n"],[99,104,117,110,107,32,"128",32,98,121,116,101,115,44,32,114,101,115,116,32,"181",32,98,121,116,101,115,"\n"],[102,105,110,100,32,104,101,97,100,101,114,32,84,121,112,101,32,"3",32,73,100,32,"4",44,32,99,104,117,110,107,32,"128",32,98,121,116,101,115,44,32,114,101,115,116,32,"52",32,98,121,116,101,115,"\n"],[76,97,115,116,32,99,104,117,110,107,32,115,105,122,101,58,32,"51","\n"],[102,105,110,100,32,104,101,97,100,101,114,32,84,121,112,101,... 

*skipped*
undefined
*unexpected termination of test process*
::{badarg,[{erlang,list_to_binary,
                   [[[100,101,99,111,100,101|...],
                     [99,104,117,110,107|...],
                     [102,105,110,100|...],
                     [76,97,115|...],
                     [102,105|...],
                     [82|...],
                     [...]|...]],
                   []},
           {eunit_proc,buffer_to_binary,1,
                       [{file,"eunit_proc.erl"},{line,276}]},
           {eunit_proc,group_leader_loop,3,
                       [{file,"eunit_proc.erl"},{line,600}]}]}

=======================================================
  Failed: 0.  Skipped: 0.  Passed: 3.
One or more tests were cancelled.
error
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите весь вывод целиком. Это просто трейс.

Answer (score 1):

Если попробовать представить параметр того `erlang:list_to_binary(...)`, который упал, получите:

```
decode rtmp, chunk id: 4
chunk 128 bytes, rest 181 bytes
find header Type 3 Id 4, chunk 128 bytes, rest 52 bytes
Last chunk size: 51
find header Type
...
```

А если посмотреть чуть ниже, будет видно `eunit_proc:group_leader_loop` из чего можно понять, что ваш тест что-то пытается напечатать в консоль в виде deeplist, это перехватывается eunit, но ожидается обычный список. Стоит проверить, каким образом это дело печатается и где нужно вызвать `lists:flatten/1`.

Comment: Данная проблема устранилась сама собой на следующий день. Из принятых мер могу только сказать о перезагрузке машины, больше такой ситуации почему-то не возникало.